# Selenium get sub elements or getText()

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor

I am very new to Selenium and Protractor. I have the following code:

```
<button id="createPage" data-button-error="true" class="concierge-button button error is-disabled" data-ng-disabled="!newPageReady" data-ng-class="{ 'error': errors.button, 'is-disabled error' : errors.button  }" data-ng-click="createnewstudioitem(designerItems[0], conciergetitle, $event)" style="">
```

and

```
<div class="summary">
  <label class="error ng-binding ng-scope" data-ng-if="errors.error || errors.category" data-ng-bind="errors.message">Remove special characters</label>
</div>
```

I am using selenium and protractor. I am trying to **either** get the value of `data-button-error="true"` or I am trying to see if the oerds `Remove special characters` is present. The reason is that I want to validate if I add special characters there is a message `Remove special characters` and the `data-button-error="true"` changes from `false` to `true`

I have tried:

```
        var addSpecialText = element.all(by.css(".error")).first();;
        expect(addSpecialText.getText()).toEqual('Remove special characters');
```

AND

```
        var addSpecialText = element.all(by.css(".error"));
        expect(addSpecialText.get(0).getText()).toEqual('Remove special characters');
```

AND

```
            var addSpecialText = element.all(by.css(".error")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

Comment: I think this error message are not appended to dom and so you won't be able to verify it. the one thing you verify is if this class is set to true or not.

Answer (score 2):

To get data-button-error using selenium:

```
String data = driver.findElement(By.id("createPage")).getAttribute("data-button-error");
```

To get "Remove special characters" using selenium:

```
String data = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".summary label")).getText();
```

Comment: i need to add the driver to my project. I get an error on the driver.

Comment: Yes, you need selenium webdriver to your project [link] (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)

WebDriver driver = new <Browser>();
Ex: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Also you can find details steps here
[link] (http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/configure-eclipse-with-selenium-webdriver/)